# I am trying Naive Bayes classification on my dataset for ML project. I am getting: " TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n' "

Tags: python, machine-learning

Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

def classify(training_tweets, test_tweets, ngram=(1, 1)):
    
    k_fold = KFold(n=len(training_tweets),n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
```

Comment: KFold doesn't have a kwarg "n". I would remove that and try running without it.

Comment: `KFold` does not take a parameter named `n`.  Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: a good place to look is the documentation. see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. But in previous versions, when Kfold was a part of cross_validation, it worked this way.

Comment: Well, that isn’t the case anymore. (The old version did use n.) https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html

Comment: yes exactly, so how can use the same logic now? because my code demands iterations. therefore im bound to use the len(training data) in KFold. How can i make it work now?